# Multiple partial views in a strongly typed view (ASP.NET MVC5) ? Unable to get relative Path In View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I am having an issue that after saving relative path I cannot get picture in a list, and having error:

> CS1061
>   `'IEnumerable<tbl_Advertisement>'` does not contain a definition for `'Imagepath'` and no extension method `'Imagepath'` accepting a first argument of type `'IEnumerable<tbl_Advertisement>'` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   GawadarHubUI    C:\Users\Omer FarooQ\Desktop\GawadarHubistan\GawadarHubUI\GawadarHubUI\Areas\Common\Views\SampleViewAD\Index.cshtml
>   73
>   Active

This rrror in just view line: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.ImagePath)` that after type `Model`. I cannot get the the property Name `ImagePath`, rather it's showing me Extension methods and methods

Controller CODE

```cs
using BLL;
using BOL;
using DAL;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace GawadarHubUI.Areas.Common.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class SampleViewADController : Controller
    {
        GawadarHubDbEntities db = new GawadarHubDbEntities();

        private AdBl objbl;
        public SampleViewADController()
        {
            objbl = new AdBl();
        }


        // GET: Common/SampleViewAD
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                var urls = objbl.GetAll().Where(x => x.isapproved == "A").ToList();
                return View(urls);
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                TempData["Msg"] = "Approve Failed : " + e1.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View code:

```html
@model IEnumerable<BOL.tbl_Advertisement>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@if (TempData["Msg"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-info">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        @TempData["Msg"].ToString()
    </div>}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("SampleViewADController", "urls")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.adtitle)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.adsociety)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.addesc)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isapproved)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.contactNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImagePath)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Size)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tbl_Category.cname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tbl_User.useremail)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.adtitle)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.adsociety)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.addesc)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.isapproved)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contactNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ImagePath)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Size)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tbl_Category.cname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tbl_User.useremail)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.adid }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.adid }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.adid })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Your error is at `@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ImagePath)` which needs to be `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)`

Comment: yeh when i buid the view in controller by default it was item.ImagePath and when i buid it , then its shows only  ~/image/imam clinic it developer1833439.PNG in table rather showing me image . And i have search alot to render image ralative path we have to use Codes like :                                                    
          <img src="@Url.Content("~/image/imam clinic it developer1833439.PNG")" width="250" alt="body" />

Comment: OR                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ImagePath)   but Aftr Model.  it is Not Showing me ImagePath.

Comment: Read my first comment - its `item.ImagePath` !

Comment: But what i Want to show Is i Want to Show Image By  Using Its relative Path , AND  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath) Shows me The name of image[text] not the Graphical Image

Comment: Then use an `img` tag! - <img src="@item.ImagePath />` (but perhaps you should actually state that in your question)

Comment: Now <img src="@item.ImagePath" width="300" height="200"  /> it is shoiwing me a height witdh box and a small sign of corupt image

Comment: And yes When i use <img src="@item.ImagePath" width="300" height="200"  /> its shows me the actual picture but in all column same picture .and yes its a 3 tier architecture application ,and relative path is in my project root directory but tha model is in BOL and repository mathods are in DAL and IN controller  i USE BLL LAYER , to not to directly acces the DAL ,SO When controler Look for GetAll ().TOLIST() it goes to BLL then DAL and THEN DATABASE

Comment: CODE FOR UPLOAD IMAGE    string FILENAME = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myad.imgfile.FileName);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(myad.imgfile.FileName); FILENAME = FILENAME + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmfff") + extension;
myad.ImagePath = "~/image/" + FILENAME;
FILENAME = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/image/"), FILENAME);
   myad.imgfile.SaveAs(FILENAME);                                                 using (GawadarHubDbEntities db = new GawadarHubDbEntities())
                    {db.tbl_Advertisement.Add(myad);
db.SaveChanges(); }     objcn.Insert(myad);    ModelState.Clear();

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ImagePath)
```

with

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)" alt="Image" />
```

Should work.

Comment: Yes It is working But Showing me image TEXT name , i Need a  Image Rather Than Text

Comment: But what i Want to show Is i Want to Show Image By Using Its relative Path , AND @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath) Shows me The name of image[text] not the Graphical Image

Comment: When i write (Model DOT ) then it doesnt show me ImagePath ,this is tha main problem iam facing . The word Model or @Model is not working in my view.

Comment: I copied your line and  Imagepath got error after Model . saying :                     Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IEnumerable<tbl_Advertisement>' does not contain a definition for 'ImagePath' and no extension method 'ImagePath' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<tbl_Advertisement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) GawadarHubUI C:\Users\Omer FarooQ\Desktop\GawadarHubistan\GawadarHubUI\GawadarHubUI\Areas\Common\Views\SampleViewAD\Index.cshtml 73 Active

Answer (score 0):

Your define that your model is a collection:

```
@model IEnumerable<BOL.tbl_Advertisement>
```

So every time you write `Model.`, you are referencing this collection.

The **collection** (`IEnumerable<BOL.tbl_Advertisement>`) has no property for `Imagepath`, as the error message tells you.

> `IEnumerable<tbl_Advertisement>` does not contain a definition for `Imagepath`

Rather, the **elements** (`tbl_Advertisement`) of the collection have this property.

This is what Stephen and Igor meant when they wrote that you need to access the `Imagepath` through the elements of the collection.

Either by looping over the collection:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
   <img src= "@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)" alt="Image" />
}
```

Or for the first element only:

```
var imagePath = Model.ElementAt(0).ImagePath;
```